# What items and covenants can lead to multiplayer opportunities?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What items and or covenants will help me find both targeted (looking for a specific player) and general (looking for multiplayer in general) opportunities to play with others online?

Specific items help different types of multiplayer. For example, the white sign soapstone will only help players with coop, while the cracked red eye orb will only help in pvp invasions.

Comment: The ring hasn't helped me match up with any friends, not sure why they put it in the game if you can't play with friends or at least I've had no luck so far matching with the inscribed ring

Answer (score 5):

The name-engraved ring makes it easier to connect to other players. Basically, when you purchase the ring you choose a god's name to inscribe on it. While wearing the ring, you have a greater chance to be matched up with players who have the same god's name on their ring.

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Name-engraved+Ring

Comment: You actually can re-select the name on the ring each time you put it on-